# how to remove brackets character in string (java)

Tags: java, regex, string, brackets

I want to remove all type of brackets character (example: [],(),{}) in string by using java.

I tried using this code:

```
String test = "watching tv (at home)"; 
test = test.replaceAll("(","");
test = test.replaceAll(")","");
```

But it's not working, help me please.

Comment: You have to add *\\* before *(* 
Try this...
String test = "watching tv (at home)"; 
test = test.replaceAll("\\(","").replaceAll("\\)","");

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To remove ***all punctuation marks*** that include all brackets, braces and sq. brackets ... as per the question is:

```
String test = "watching tv (at home)"; 
test = test.replaceAll("\\p{P}","");
```

Comment: @MuhammadHaryadiFutra Be careful this solution removes also symbols like `.`, `,`, `;`, etc.

Comment: this just don't remove brackets but also other characters like "/" and "-".  etc 
(16180856-04-20170407-ad/wav/D104) changed to 
161808560420170407adwavD104

Comment: @AdnanAli please read the answer correctly if you miss that then read the comment above your :)

Comment: This removes other symbols too. So if someone uses this without knowing that, it might cause major issues

Answer (score 38):

The first argument of `replaceAll` takes a regular expression.

All the brackets have meaning in regex: Brackets are used in regex to reference [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html), 
square brackets are used for [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) & braces are used for matched character occurrence. 
Therefore they all need to be escaped...However here the characters can simply be enclosed in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with just escaping required for square brackets

```
test = test.replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}]","");
```

Answer (score 6):

The first argument passed to the `replaceAll()` method should be a regular expression. If you want to match those literal bracket characters you need to escape `\\(`, `\\)` them.

You could use the following to remove bracket characters. [Unicode property `\p{Ps}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) will match any kind of opening bracket and [Unicode property `\p{Pe}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) matches any kind of closing bracket.

```
String test = "watching tv (at home) or [at school] or {at work}()[]{}";
test = test.replaceAll("[\\p{Ps}\\p{Pe}]", "");
System.out.println(test); //=> "watching tv at home or at school or at work"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the bracket as it will be treated as part of a regex

```
String test = "watching tv (at home)"; 
test = test.replaceAll("\\(","");
test = test.replaceAll("\\)","");
```

Also to remove all brackets try

```
String test = "watching tv (at home)"; 
test = test.replaceAll("[\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]","");
```

Comment: `"\("` will cause a compilation error as it is not a valid escape character.  `"\\("` is what is needed

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String.replace` instead of `String.replaceAll` for **better performance**, as it searches for the exact sequence and does not need regular expressions.

```
String test = "watching tv (at home)"; 
test = test.replace("(", " ");
test = test.replace(")", " ");
test = test.replace("[", " ");
test = test.replace("]", " ");
test = test.replace("{", " ");
test = test.replace("}", " ");
```

If you are working with texts I recommend you to replace the brackets with an empty space to avoid words joining together: `watching tv(at home) -> watching tvat home`

Answer (score 0):

subject =StringUtils.substringBetween(subject, "[", "]")

Answer (score 0):

String list= '[{121223123123123123}]';

String accountlist= list.replaceAll("[\[\]]","");

In this case I am removing [ ] from a string.

Output : String list= '{121223123123123123}';

Comment: no, it's replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "")

Answer (score 0):

For removing Brackets and other punctuations from the String you can use

```
String test = "watching tv (at home)"; 
test = test.replaceAll("\\p{P}","");
```

But if are you are intending for numbers only Phone Number, the below will be useful:

```
test = test.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
```

it will remove all non digit characters from the string.