# regular expression remove () brases

Tags: java, regex, spring

```
String abc=folderDocBean.getService().replaceAll("\\s+", "_");
```

**abc** = `hello world (English)` or `hello world ((((English`

**expected output**:- `hello_world_English`

In the above line it removes white spaces and ads `_` in the place of whitespace..

I want to remove the braces if matching braces `()` exists then all braces the braces need to remove.

I have tried with `abc.replaceAll("\\p{P}","");` is removing the braces but not ading any underscore to my string

```
abc = abc.replaceAll("\\s+", "_");
        abc = abc.replaceAll("[\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]",""); ==> it is satisfying my reqirement and how can I write the same in a single statement
```

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: see how to use `[]` in regex to replace more than one character

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to remove the braces if matching braces(1 open 1 close) exists, all braces, or the content between matching braces?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove brackets character in string (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852961/how-to-remove-brackets-character-in-string-java)

Comment: Then your expected output is wrong in your example.

Comment: @sn42 I want to remove the braces if matching braces(1 open 1 close) exists, all braces

Comment: You should really update your question with some clear defintions on what is supposed to happen. For example what would happen with `hello         world ((((English`?

Comment: `s.replaceAll("^\\W+|\\W+$", "").replaceAll("\\W+", "_")`

Comment: Two input, only one output .... see how to create a [mcve] ...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is not working

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `abc.replaceAll("\\p{P}","");` is removing the braces but not ading any underscore to my string

Comment: You might try: `string.replaceAll("\\s+\\(+|\\s+", "_").replaceAll("\\)+", "");`.

Comment: [My suggestion works well](https://ideone.com/f8f4UU). *it is satisfying my reqirement and how can I write the same in a single statement* - it will look ugly in Java, I do not recommend it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is working well. I have not tested good.my apologies

Comment: can you please post the same as answer and explain something about that regex

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/34207035/8089107

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to replace multiple matched Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180794/how-to-replace-multiple-matched-regex)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - Your suggestion may work well but that's a matter of opinion. Your suggestion also removes **ALL** non-word characters (not just parentheses) from the string the expression is working against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the replacement using a single expression `[()\\[\\]{}|]|\\s+`, but that will require using a `StringBuffer`. Here is how you can do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String abc = "hello world ((((English)) {test}";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[()\\[\\]{}|]|\\s+");
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(abc);
    StringBuffer bufStr = new StringBuffer();
    while(m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(bufStr, m.group().contains(" ") ? "_" : "");
    }
    m.appendTail(bufStr);
    System.out.println(bufStr);
}
```

So basically you have a combined regular expression which intercepts all brackets or multiple spaces and then you loop through all matches and whenever a match is found you analyse the match with `m.group().contains(" ")`. According to whether the match contains a space or not you append either `"_"` or an empty string.

If you run the code above you will get this output:

```
hello_world_English_test
```