# How to remove brackets character in string (dart)

Tags: regex, string, dart

tested this [how to remove brackets character in string (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852961/how-to-remove-brackets-character-in-string-java) but it doens't worked in Dart. Any tipps to remove ( ) in a String?

My Code:

```
  String num = (85);
  num.replaceAll("\\p{P}", "");
```

Result should be: 85

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a compiled `RegExp` object with `unicode: true` argument:

```dart
String num = "(85)";
print(num.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\p{P}", unicode: true), ""));
```

This outputs `85` as `\p{P}` is now treated as a punctuation proper matching Unicode property class regex.

Comment: thank Wiktor, this works like a charm

Comment: how about double quoted string and curly braces ?

Comment: @TonyHart `\p{P}` only matches punctuation proper, if you need to match any punctuation and symbols, you need `[\p{P}\p{S}]`.